# Свернуть Toolbar и спрятать TabLayout при прокрутке

Tags: android, coordinator-layout, collapsing-toolbar-layout

Моя разметка:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".sferaActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/nav_header_bg"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/myToolBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ru.qwerq.qwerq.MyNestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ru.qwerq.qwerq.WrapContentHeightViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ru.qwerq.qwerq.MyNestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="ru.qwerq.qwerq.FAB_Float_on_Scroll"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Как при прокрутке спрятать табы под toolbar? То есть при прокрутке toolbar остается, а табы уходят под него. Скажу сразу, `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` для TabLayout не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/admin_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:tag="portrait">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_background"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/AdmTitleMain"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTitleText"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dark_background"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
                    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/adminRefreshMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/admin_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/admin_drawer_menu" />
```

у меня так работает

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо вынести `Toolbar` из `CoordinatorLayout`. Изменений много надо сделать вроде как. Вот рабочий код. Ориентируйтесь по нему

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar_container">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/id_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: я его смотрел, у меня он не работает, даже в таком виде, без изменений